# Cucumber: "Given" step must test something

Tags: cucumber

I'm reworking my tests into Cucumber, but I must still use some user-provided information (namely, an account that the tests should be run against):

```
Given a valid account
When I ...
Then I ...
```

Because of this, I must check the validity of the provided account during the "Given" step, and fail the scenario if it's invalid. What would be the correct way of doing so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way I've seen of going about this is to run in a temporary environment where you can mock a valid user. So in your `Given` step you should create a new, valid user. Then run the rest of your test and remove the user after the test exits.